# How to run a database independent of a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, soa

How can I separate a database and rails app into two different containers? The tutorial on Docker shows how to create the two with the `docker-compose` set-up, however I'm more curious on how to set this up manually so that I can play around with SOA on Docker.

Comment: Google: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-on-docker

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of your db container

db stop/rm/pull/run:

```
# First three lines are for teardown/reubuild
#!/bin/bash
docker stop myapp-postgres
docker rm myapp-postgres
docker pull postgres
docker run --name myapp-postgres -t -i -d postgres
```

app stop/rm/pull/run:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker stop myapp
docker rm myapp
docker pull dockerhubname/myapp
docker run -d -t -i --link myapp-postgres:postgres -p 80:80 --name myapp dockerhubname/myapp       

#spit out some useful info
docker ps
MYAPP_MACHINE=$(docker ps | grep myapp | awk '{print $1}')
echo $MYAPP_MACHINE
docker exec -ti $MYAPP_MACHINE ps -aux
```